# Enabling developer tools on a NACL page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, google-nativeclient

I'd like to debug a website that is using NACL, however the only way to access the site is through the NACL start page (see the picture below).

[image: NACL start page]

From this page, there is no way to access the developer tools and hence the debugger.

Is there a way to enable the Chrome debugger on a NACL website?

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/devguide/devcycle/debugging

nacl-gdb is the tool for debugging -- single stepping instructions, inspecting memory, etc, like a normal native-code debugger.

Comment: can I debug the javascripts of the web page and inspect the DOM like with Chrome's developer tools?